# Beautify JSON output using Python and remove this \" from output

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON out from a function:

```
output = user_schema.dump(users).data
output = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in output], default=alchemyencoder)
print output

return jsonify({'user' : output})
```

The alchemyencode looks like this:

```
def alchemyencoder(obj):
"""JSON encoder function for SQLAlchemy special classes."""
if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
    return obj.isoformat()
elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
    return float(obj)
```

And my output looks like this:

```
 {  "user": "[{\"latitude\": 28.6167, \"admin_name1\": \"New Delhi\", \"key\": \"IN/110051\", \"longitude\": 77.2167, \"place_name\": \"Azad Nagar\"}]" }
```

I want to remove \" from the output and beautify my JSON to look like this:

```
user:
   {
         latitude : 23.233,
         longitude :24.223,
         place : "xyz"
   }
```

Comment: Your `json` is not what you expect it to be.  It has the value of `'user'` is actually a string instead of a dictionary.  You'll need to change your output first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that:

```
output = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in output], default=alchemyencoder)
```

*Already creates a JSON string*.

You then put that json string in a `dict`, and then *serialize it again*:

```
return jsonify({'user' : output})
```

Those back-slash escapes are necessary because the result:

```
 {  "user": "[{\"latitude\": 28.6167, \"admin_name1\": \"New Delhi\", \"key\": \"IN/110051\", \"longitude\": 77.2167, \"place_name\": \"Azad Nagar\"}]" }
```

Is a JSON object with a single key-value pair, user, and a string, not a JSON array of objects.

Simply leave out the `json.dumps` line, and simply return:

```
return json.dumps({'user':[dict(r) for r in output]}, default=alchemyencoder)
```

Comment: but I need this user word also. I tried to remove this :
output = json.dumps([dict(r) for r in output], default=alchemyencoder) but then my decimal type is not serializable. Is there any way I can include alchemyencoder in jsonify

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha yes, so `json.dumps({'user' : output}, default=alchemyencoder)` and don't use `jsonify`

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

# Using the string provided in your example
j = '{  "user": "[{\"latitude\": 28.6167, \"admin_name1\": \"New Delhi\", \"key\": \"IN/110051\", \"longitude\": 77.2167, \"place_name\": \"Azad Nagar\"}]" }'

j = j.replace('"[','[').replace(']"',']')

print(json.dumps(json.loads(j), indent=2))
{
  "user": [
    {
      "latitude": 28.6167,
      "admin_name1": "New Delhi",
      "key": "IN/110051",
      "longitude": 77.2167,
      "place_name": "Azad Nagar"
    }
  ]
}
```